# What is the best practice to show logfiles within a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Sometimes it might be useful to paste the content of a log file related to a question. If the part of the log a short one the markdown for code might be good enough to embed the text into the question:

```
Logfile line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

But what should be used for log files that have hundreds of lines that could be relevant to answer a question?

1. Should I upload the file somewhere?
2. Should I use a service like pastebin.com? If yes, is there something similar for the Ubuntu community?
3. Should I paste it as code anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to include a really big log file the recommended method is to upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link in your question.

Comment: [`pastebinit`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pastebinit/)!

Comment: It is best to post the relevant lines, error messages and warnings . People do not want to read the same message over and over and long lines of normal logs or repetitive warnings are boring.

Comment: If you don't know what is relevant, it is best to post al the logs.